# How to set up windows so its possible to boot non Apple laptops from it?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, ssd, windows

I have an old Macbook and a new Windows laptop. I want to install Windows 7 on the Mac's Samsung 850 EVO SSD so that its possible to use it on both Macbook and the Windows laptop.

1. Is such a thing possible?
2. If yes, how does one do that?

Here's why I need to do this. (feel free to skip this)

The (2008) Macbook is my personal laptop but Windows one is for work. I want to avoid using work laptop if possible. I'm taking classes for professional exams and my LMS software is compatible with only windows. The institute is basically being a **** and is saying if my mac's logic board gives out (which I think it might), I need to pay about $200 extra since its not possible to generate a new key or something like that.

So I need to be able to just plug in the samsung SSD in a windows laptop so that its ready to use. I have exams in 3 months.

Comment: So set up a Virtual Machine and keep the files in the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that you'd have to ring Microsoft to reinstate your licence every time you swapped, Windows is not very good at swapping hardware.

A Mac drive can be used to boot any Mac older than the OS on the drive; Windows doesn't work that way, you'd need a bare-metal clone & install the correct drivers every time.

Comment: Assuming that I install windows through bootcamp. 
will buying a macbook (older than the OS) and updating the drivers for windows enable me to use the new laptop exactly like the old one?

Comment: Installing Windows on BC isn't the issue - attempting to move the install from machine to machine is what will fail. That one of them is a Mac is almost irrelevant, you can't even do it between 2 PCs unless they are identical. Even if 'identical' they will have different part serial numbers, forcing you to ring Microsoft every time you swap machine.